# Validate binary search tree of comparables in a single pass

Tags: python, algorithm, tree, binary-search-tree

The usual algorithm of validating a binary search tree is to recursively check that each value is within a range of valid numbers, splitting that range in two on each node.

Some sample Python to illustrate the algorithm (for non-duplicate values):

```
def walker(node, low, high):
    if node is None:
        return True
    if not (low < node.data < high):
        return False

    return walker(node.left, low, node.data) and walker(node.right, node.data, high)

def checkBST(root):
    if root is None:
        return True
    return walker(root, -2**32, 2**32)
```

This assumes that the values are integers, and that they are all within `(-2^32, 2^32)`.

What if I wanted to write this algorithm for any type that is comparable? Finding the smallest and largest values in the tree can be done in linear time using another pass over the tree, but is there a way that doesn't require two full passes?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in `O(2*log n + n)` time, for a balanced tree, which is very close to a single pass.

If the binary search tree is valid, the smallest element is found by walking down the left subtrees until the end.

```
def least(node):
    if node.left is None:
        return node.data
    return least(node.left)
```

Similarly, the largest element is found by walking down the right subtrees until the end.

```
def most(node):
    if node.right is None:
        return node.data
    return most(node.right)
```

Since we're assuming `least(root)` gives us the smallest value in the tree, and `most(root)` gives us the largest value, all other values should be in the range `(least(root), most(root))`.

If the tree is not valid, there will be a smaller value `s` somewhere in the tree such that `s < least(root)`, and/or a larger value `l` somewhere in the tree such that `most(root) < l`. Either of these will fail the `(low < node.data < high)` validation step.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to find the smallest and largest values. You can simply deactivate constraint checking on the parts of the tree with no lower or upper bound.

In Python you can simply use a `None` object, or any other object, to express that the lower or upper bound constraint is *not active*. For example:

```
def walker(node, low = None, high = None):
    if node is None:
        return True
    if low is not None and low >= node.data:
        return False
    if high is not None and high <= node.data:
        return False
    return walker(node.left, low, node.data) and walker(node.right, node.data, high)

def checkBST(root):
    if root is None:
        return True
    return walker(root) # look ma, no parameters
```

In [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x), the `None` is considered not orderable. Neverthless if it is (in for instance another programming language), then you simply have to invent a system (for instance passing additional parameters) that specify that a lowerbound or upperbound is *active*.

You can for instance define four methods to define a tree, like:

```
def lwalker(node, low):
    if node is None:
        return True
    if low >= node.data:
        return False
    return lwalker(node.right,low) and luwalker(node.left, low, node.data)

def uwalker(node, upper):
    if node is None:
        return True
    if upper <= node.data:
        return False
    return uwalker(node.left,upper) and luwalker(node.right, node.data, upper)

def luwalker(node, low, upper):
    if node is None:
        return True
    if low >= node.data or upper <= node.data:
        return False
    return luwalker(node.left,low,node.data) and luwalker(node.right,node.data, upper)

def checkBST(root):
    if root is None:
        return True
    return uwalker(root.left,root.data) and lwalker(root.right,root.data)
```